# UITextfield blurred text

Tags: iphone, sdk, uitextfield, blurry

**Hy,...**
So u can see that my test is blurred at the UITextfield in my cell. But I search in the internet about it, and the only solution is to use int-coordinates and I do that!
But when I push to my other subview's ('Kollege', 'Fahrten', etc.) then the text gets more blurred and when I want to write another text in the textfield there is still this text and doesn't clear when I push the delete-button!

Please help :)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds (and looks) like you might be piling multiple text fields on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a font height like 14,5? If so, just change it to 14 or 15, that helped for me.

Comment: Nope, i think it was the problem that I always add a new uitextfield :D  --  noobie fail